# View overlapping when using RelativeLayout Parameters

Tags: android, android-layout

My RelativeLayout Dynamically adds check boxes and sets text to each of them but they all overlap each other even though i'm using the RelativeLayout.BELOW parameter.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bible_progress);
    Bundle progressBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int positionBook = progressBundle.getInt("position");

    if(positionBook == 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            RelativeLayout progressLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress_layout);
            CheckBox progressBox = new CheckBox(this);
            progressBox.setText("Dynamic Checkbox " + i);
            progressBox.setId(i + 10);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, progressBox.getId());
            progressBox.setLayoutParams(params);
            progressLayout.addView(progressBox);
        }
    }

}
```

Im not getting any errors so there is no stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are providing the wrong id to the rule

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, progressBox.getId());
```

this way you are providing the id of the view you just created, to the rule